# Replace value with variable length between double quotes

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a string like:

```
schedule="0.25"
```

and I want to replace the `0.25` lets say with `0.50`

I could achieve this with:

```
sed 's/\"....\"/\"0\.50\"/g'
```

the problem is I don't know the value between the double quotes, and therefore I do not know the length. It could be any value, but it will be always preceded by `schedule=`.

Comment: It depends... you might try something like `sed 's/\"[^"]*\"/\"0.50\"/g'`(this matches 0 or more characters that aren't '"' between '"' for replacement).

Comment: @vonbrand this is pretty much what steeldriver suggested in his answer... (apart from the escapes).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `[^"]*` to match a sequence of zero or more non-`"` characters. So

```
$ echo 'schedule="0.25"' | sed 's/"[^"]*"/"0.5"/'
schedule="0.5"
```

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you just want to replace whatever comes after the equal sign with `"0.50"`.  This is easily done with `awk`:

```
$ echo 'schedule="0.25"' | awk -F = 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } $1 == "schedule" { $2 = "\"0.50\"" } { print }'
schedule="0.50"
```

The `awk` program looks specifically for a record whose 1st `=`-delimited field is `schedule`.  When found, it replaces the second field with `"0.50"`.

If `0.50` is variable, you may pass this value into the `awk` script like this:

```
$ newval=0.222
$ echo 'schedule="0.25"' | awk -v nv="$newval" -F = 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } $1 == "schedule" { $2 = sprintf("\"%s\"", nv) } { print }'
schedule="0.222"
```

And obviously, if `schedule` may vary as well,

```
$ newval=0.222
$ variable=schedule
$ echo 'schedule="0.25"' | awk -v v="$variable" -v nv="$newval" -F = 'BEGIN { OFS=FS } $1 == v { $2 = sprintf("\"%s\"", nv) } { print }'
schedule="0.222"
```

---

With `sed`, you could just ignore whatever comes after the `=` and replace it with whatever you wish:

```
$ echo 'schedule="0.25"' | sed 's/=.*/="0.50"/'
schedule="0.50"
```

To make sure we replace only the value for `schedule`, and not some other setting's value,

```
$ echo 'schedule="0.25"' | sed '/^schedule=/s/=.*/="0.50"/'
schedule="0.50"
```

This puts a condition on our substitution; The line must have the string `schedule=` at the start of it for it to trigger.

We could even insert shell variables into our `sed` expression, but be aware that we must make sure that the values of these variables do not break the `sed` syntax (by containing characters that affect the matching or the delimiting of the commands):

```
$ newval=0.222
$ variable=schedule
$ echo 'schedule="0.25"' | sed "/^$variable=/s/=.*/=\"$newval\"/"
schedule="0.222"
```

As opposed to the `awk` example, here we rely on the shell to inject the values of our variables into the `sed` editing script.  This would normally be classified as a code injection vulnerability in the cases where the values of the variables are not under our control (like when we are reading them from a user supplied source).

Answer (score 1):

If you are invoking sed/awk from a bash script/terminal, then you could avoid using the external tools and take advantage of bash's own string processing capabilities:

```
$ a='schedule="0.25"'
$ echo "$a"
schedule="0.25"
$ b="${a/\"*/\"0.50\"}"
$ echo "$b"
schedule="0.50"
```

Comment: Shorter: `b="${a/\"*/\"0.50\"}"`.  Note that you're using filename globbing patterns here, not regular expressions, so your `*` just matches the rest of the string anyway.  A standard compliant variation would be `b="${a%%=*}"'="0.50"'`.